# How do I manipulate this equation to show they are equal without actually calculating it $\sqrt{3}\cdot \tan(\frac{\pi}{12})+3 = 2\sqrt{3}$

Tags: geometry

I calculated both sides to be $3.4641016151377544$.
Hopefully, the LaTeX shows up in the title but if not here it is again:
$\sqrt{3}\cdot \tan(\frac{\pi}{12})+3 =  2\sqrt{3}$
I'm cutting 8 congruent shapes out of fabric to build a sphere. Having this equality known will help me construct it more accurately, using a compass instead of a bunch of lengths and angles. I can tell from the calculation that they are equal but my curiosity got the best of me and I am just wondering if the terms can be expressed differently to prove they are equal without calculating the sqrts or the tan.

By the way it totally possible that I forgot some axioms or something and made some assumptions about this shape that aren't true. Here's a pic of my theoretical sketch:

[image]

Comment: Per the posted answers, it is difficult to imagine verifying the equation without basing it on **something**.  This means that you specifically have to focus on the fact that the angle that you are taking the tangent of, is $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{12}.$  I suppose that the only alternative to the trigonometry approaches in the two answers would be some sort of purely geometric demonstration.  For example, you might consider constructing an isosceles triangle, with two of the angles equal to $ \dfrac{\pi}{12},$ and see where this leads.  Hard to imagine a purely geometric demonstration, though.

Comment: @user2661923 It is not possible to have a *purely* geometric demonstration, because one is trying to find the exact value of a trigonometric ratio. However, one way that is pretty much as "geometric" as it gets is as follows: start with a square of side $2$. construct an equilateral triangle within the square such that the base of it is exactly the top side of the square. Now join the bottom two vertices of the sq. to the apex of the triangle. Show by pure geometric axioms (fairly trivial) that the base angles of the resulting isosceles triangle are each equal to $\frac{\pi}{12}$. (continued).

Comment: Now deduce by Pythagoras' (applied to an appropriate bisection of the equilateral triangle) that the height of the isosceles triangle is $2 - \sqrt 3$, and the rest is very obvious.

Comment: @Deepak I request that you transfer your comments into an **answer**, referring (in your answer) to my comment.  I feel that your analysis deserves to be posted as a separate answer.

Comment: @user2661923 Done. Same answer, though. Didn't feel right making a new one.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{3}$ is *irrational*, so is $2\sqrt{3}$, so both sides *do not equal* $3.4641016151377544$; that is only an approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The key thing is to show $\tan \frac{\pi}{12} = 2 - \sqrt 3$.

To do this, note that $\tan \frac {\pi}6 = \frac 1{\sqrt 3}$. This can easily be derived from the special $(1,\sqrt 3, 2)$ right triangle which you can construct by bisecting an equilateral triangle of side $2$.

By the double-angle formula for tangent, $\tan 2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2x}$

If you let $\tan \frac{\pi}{12} = t$, you can now write:

$\frac{2t}{1-t^2} = \frac 1{\sqrt 3}$.

Try solving that exactly in radicals. The rest should be easy.

EDIT: As requested by user2661923, I have included a more "geometric" approach, with reference to the figure above. The top triangle is equilateral, the bottom one is isosceles, and both triangles exist within a square of side $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we have

$$\tan(x/2)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\implies \tan(\pi/12)=\frac{1-\cos(\pi/6)}{\sin(\pi/6)}$$

And you can finish now.

Comment: Corrected a small typo. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Deepak Thank you.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Applying the [formula for $\tan(a+b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238692/) (which has plenty of proofs, including geometric) to $a=\frac\pi3$ and $b=-\frac\pi4$, we get$$\tan\frac\pi{12}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{1+\sqrt3}=2-\sqrt3.$$